# Error handling ClientContext CSOM SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, csom

What is the best way to handle errors for `ClientContext` is there a reference material for errors thrown. When using the `HTTPWebRequest` you can check the status ie 403, 500. is there anything similar for the `ClientContext`.

I would like to implement some kind of retry etc or re authenticate if anything fails

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the normal pattern

```
try {
    ...
}
catch (Exception) {
    //Get error code and act
}
finally {
    ...
}
```

Here is a nice [blog](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/sharepoint-2010-exception-handling.html) which explains

1. Problem with this try/catch/finally approach
2. How to use ExceptionHandlingScope?
3. Comparison

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there is any reference material regarding what errors can come back from an exception?

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.Throttling

Comment: You can look for HTTP Response Error codes and use that.

Answer (score 1):

For server side exception handling in SharePoint 2010 and onwards you can use an [ExceptionHandlingScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.exceptionhandlingscope.aspx) to provide server side fallback behaviour.

MSDN has a guide on how to use it which can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee534976(v=office.14).aspx

To summarize:

- Instantiate an ExceptionHandlingScope object, and within a using
  scope of it's [StartScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ee546747.aspx) method

  - Place your CSOM query within a using
    scope of [StartTry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ee543419.aspx)
  - Place your exception handling code within a
    using scope of [StartCatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ee544036.aspx)
  - Place your finalize handling code
    within a using scope of [StartFinally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ee542342.aspx)
- Finally, after the StartScope using scope, call ExecuteQuery

e.g.

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection");            
ExceptionHandlingScope scope = new ExceptionHandlingScope(clientContext);            
using (scope.StartScope())
{
  using (scope.StartTry())
  {
    // CSOM query code which may fail here
  }
  using (scope.StartCatch())
  {                    
    // CSOM fallback code here          
  }
  using (scope.StartFinally())
  {                    
    // CSOM finally code here                           
  }
}
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```